# Java HttpsURLConnection SSLSocketFactory timeout with trustAllCerts

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, timeout, httpsurlconnection, sslsocketfactory

```java
 SSLSocket socket = null;
 SSLContext sc = null;
 sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
 SSLSocketFactory sslSocfactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
  
 //--- Method-1 connection -----
    socket = (SSLSocket)sslSocfactory.createSocket(host, port);
    socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);          

 //--- Method-2 connection -----
    socket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout); //- This timeout works for my situation
    socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

Using Method-1 to connect works. It trusts all certificates, even self-signed certs, but the timeout does not work as well as Method-2, but when I use Method-2 not all certs are trusted, and it fails for self-signed certs.
I understand that this is because in Method-2 I did not use my sslSocfactory which incorporates the trustAllCerts. I can't figure out how to incorporate my sslSocfactory into Method-2. I've tried a few ways, but the compile fails.

Comment: Why don't you use the same method to obtain the socket for method 2 as you do for method 1? Why not simply the same line `socket = (SSLSocket)sslSocfactory.createSocket(host, port);`?

Comment: Hi,
When I try this as you suggest:
     socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
     socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
I get this runtime error:
   java.net.SocketException: already connected

I have to somehow utilize InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout) because this is the only way timeout works as I need it to. Because setSoTimeout(timeout) only works for one of these: connect or handshake, I forget which one.